# Invalid Argument on API Call?

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access

I am getting an invalid argument with the following API Call (following https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/doorbell-battery#webrtc):

```
curl -X POST   'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/projectID/devices/deviceID:executeCommand'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   
-H 'Authorization: AUTHTOKEN'   --data-raw '{
    "command" : "sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream",
    "params" : {
            "offerSdp" : "a=recvonly"
          }
    }'
```

Response from server:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What is the invalid argument?

Comment: You need `Authorization: Bearer SOME-TOKEN`

Comment: Are projectID and deviceID correct?

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that is not a valid offer, and you need to use a web rtc client to create it.  See webrtc.org for examples.

Answer (score 0):

`"offerSdp" : "a=recvonly"` isn't a valid offer, but also you will get that `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error if you don't end your offer string with a `\r\n` character.